# How do I NOT Nazar someone else

Tags: nazar, evil-eye

What does Hinduism say about not giving Nazar or evil eye to someone else.

Last Diwali we had lunch party at office.

There was young lady who was prettier than me and her Anarkali suited her well. She was super friendly and even gave me a bindi to wear.

The Whole time at the Diwali party I felt inadequate

- why did I wear black salwar  kameez instead of something colorful
- Why didn’t I wear jewelry
- Why didn’t I have a simple bindi
- Why didn’t I smile and be confide like this young lady

I even told my non-Desi coworkers that I never seen someone look so beautiful and pulled together and for next Diwali I need to step up my game (it’s in less than three months now,)

I went up to the young lady and complimented her and asked where did she purchase that Anarkali and she gave name of shop in Canada

But afterwards I think she was avoiding me

Due I give her Nazar? I did nit see her

How to NOT give people Nazar? I know it is absolutely horrible when someone gives it to you (my Father is suffering from it, but it was much before the Diwali incident)

Comment: Well in short it's all about your mind and the thoughts you create plus the real intention behind those thoughts, so when your thoughts, your words and your actions are in sync plus they are positive then perhaps the outcome will be positive as well, hope you are getting my point.

Comment: I am trying to understand. When I saw this younger, prettier lady I thought, how do I step up my game. I did not want any I’ll will towards her. By the same token a handsome dentist with three beautiful daughters who are also dentists gave my Dad compliments and appreciation about how he looks decades younger. That same day my Dads knee pain got worse. Few months later Knee Dr said if he dont fix he will be in wheelchair. And he cannot do surgery right now because around same time Cardiologist says he has severe aortic stenosis and must go for TAVR. Honestly I am nervous and upset by Nazar!